# FullCalendar sends array in single query param, Rails expects repeated param per array value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

In Rails 6 and [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed) v5.11, when passing form parameters in FullCalendar's `addEventSource()` method via `extraParams`, array parameters are added to the url query string in a single parameter rather than repeated per value as expected by Rails.

E.G. with `extraParams: { "staff_id[]": ["123", "139"] }`,
FullCalendar adds it to the url in the form:
`staff_id[]=123,139`

but Rails requires it in the query string as:

`staff_id[]=123&staff_id[]=139`

Any suggestions on how to get FullCalendar to send arrays in the query string format expected by Rails?
There are multiple filters so it is awkward to wrestle the strings from Rails params back into arrays in the controller (in this example the controller Parameters receive `"staff_id"=>["123,139"]` instead of `"staff_id"=>["123", "139"]`)

**Update:** [jQuery.get()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) generates url parameters in the form `key[]=1&key[]=2`, as required by Rails controllers, for arrays in its `data` argument. Can FullCalendar be made do the same?

**Update:** FullCalendar's `encodeParams()` function is responsible for this:

```
function encodeParams(params) {
    var parts = [];
    for (var key in params) {
        parts.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params[key]));
    }
    return parts.join('&');
}
```

Overwriting this code locally with `jQuery.param(params)` works.

Comment: Firstly this confirms the issue as you describe it: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/wvpEmLo (although I assume you meant `{ "staff_id[]": ["123", "139"] }` as the `Array` bit is not valid JS syntax).

Comment: However I'm not sure there's anything we can do about it here. It appears to be an issue with the way fullcalendar (and/or any library it may use to run XHR requests) serialises such data. I think you'd need to [raise a bug](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs) with the fullCalendar project to try and get it resolved, or get some advice on how the internals work and therefore if there's a workaround. The members of the proejct are not regular contributors on Stackoverflow. Here we can mainly assist you with configuring / using the calendar, not fixing bugs within it, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh right, The "Array [" syntax shows in Firefox dev tools when expanding Object { utf8: "✓", "staff_id[]": (2) […] } 
I've removed that from the Q now.
I updated the Q having found the offending code and replaced it. I'll look at raising a bug report. Will I just leave this Q here or what's best @ADyson? Thanks

Comment: Yeah I think it's just how Firefox displays it in the debugging console. I don't really know about leaving the question here, I mean it's not really answerable as such, but it is a pointer to anyone who encounters something similar as to where to go - perhaps if you raise a bug you could post the link to it here in the comments.